# Array de subclasses de uma superclasse em Delphi XE7

Tags: array, delphi, pascal

Estou tentando fazer um Array de subclasses neste formato:

```
 arrayReg : Array[0..1] of TRegDom = (TRegDom0000);
```

Sendo TRegDom0000 uma subclasse de TRegDom (TRegDom0000(TRegDom)) e dá um erro de "*Tipos incompatíveis E2010*":

> 'TRegDom' and 'class of TRegDom0000'

Comment: Não consegui entender muito bem o que você quer fazer... se você quer inicializar o array, acredito que você tenha que colocar uma instância da classe onde você colocou a classe TRegDom0000

Comment: Eu preciso desse array para que eu possa percorrer todos os descendentes do TRegDom, todos os métodos estão como class functions / procedures, pq eu não preciso instanciar elas. AI eu queria um array com todas as subclasses, eu faço isso em JAVA exatamente dessa forma com superclasse e subclasse mas não ta funcionando no Delphi.

Comment: Posso estar enganado mas acredito que não é possível criar esse array em Delphi/Pascal, provavelmente a forma de fazer deva ser totalmente diferente

Comment: Fazer isto ao inicializar o array nao dá. Mas penso que pode faze-lo no corpo do codigo, com um cast

Answer (score 0):

Tem que declarar types para os arrays para poder fazer o cast.
Algo como

```
MyParentClass = class
end;

MyChildClass = class(MyParentClass)
end;

TArrayOFMyParentClass = array of MyParentClass;
TArrayOFMyChildClass = array of MyChildClass;
```

E depois entao no codigo pode fazer

```
procedure TForm6.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  parentArr: TArrayOFMyParentClass;
  childArr: TArrayOFMyChildClass;
begin
  setlength(childArr, 20);

  parentArr := TArrayOFMyParentClass(childArr);
end;
```